# Использование array, полученного в результате select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне нужно использовать результат выборки, которая возвращает массив в качестве части другого селекта. Внутренний селект работает и возрващает массив корректно, но вставленный во внешний селект он ругается. Как это правильно сделать?

```sql
SELECT 
  name,
  age,
  SELECT array_agg(id) 
    FROM table_1
    WHERE parameter = 1,
  FROM table_2
  WHERE some_fake_param = 100;
```

Вот эта часть работает нормально:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(id) 
    FROM table_1
    WHERE parameter = 1,
```

И возвращет что-то типа `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: Попробуйте взять его в скобки и назначить алиас

Comment: @NickProskuryakov просто скобки работают без алиаса, спасибо!

Comment: Ок, добавил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте взять его в скобки и назначить алиас:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  age,
  (SELECT array_agg(id) 
    FROM table_1
    WHERE parameter = 1) as array
  FROM table_2
  WHERE some_fake_param = 100;
```